# ValueError Cannot assign "<QuerySet "ReplyItemPrice.item" must be a "RequestForQuotationItem" instance

Tags: python, django

- also any advise you on how to design the reply model is welcomed.
- or even how to better structure the views
- The items are created under one parent through a formset

**what am trying to archive**

- unit_price, item_total_price are associated with a single item
- delivery_charges , overall_total, subtotal are associated with all the items models,

> ```
> class RfqFullPrice(models.Model):
>     sender = models.name = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="quote_sender")`
>     receiver = models.name = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="quote_reciever")
>     requestedquotation = models.ForeignKey(RequestForQuotation, related_name="replyprice_rfq", on_delete=models.CASCADE) 
>     subtotal = MoneyField(max_digits=14, decimal_places=2, default_currency='USD', validators=[MinMoneyValidator(0)])
>     delivery_charges = MoneyField(max_digits=14, decimal_places=2, default_currency='USD', validators=[MinMoneyValidator(0)])
>     overall_total = MoneyField(max_digits=14, decimal_places=2, default_currency='USD', validators=[MinMoneyValidator(0)])
>     validity_start_date = models.DateField()
>     validity_end_date = models.DateField()
>
>  class ReplyItemPrice(models.Model):
>     full_price = models.ForeignKey(RfqFullPrice, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='full_price')
>     the_rfq = models.ForeignKey(RequestForQuotation, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
>     item = models.ForeignKey(RequestForQuotationItem, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="rfq_item")
>     quantity = models.CharField(max_length = 200, help_text='Enter the qauntity')
>     unit_price = MoneyField(max_digits=14, decimal_places=2, default_currency='USD', validators=[MinMoneyValidator(0)])
>     item_total_price = MoneyField(max_digits=14, decimal_places=2, default_currency='USD', validators=[MinMoneyValidator(0)])  
>
> def quote(request, pk):
>     template_name = 'request_quote/send_quote.html'
>     requestedquotation = get_object_or_404(RequestForQuotation, pk=pk)
>     items = RequestForQuotationItem.objects.filter(item=requestedquotation)
>
> if request.method == 'GET':
>     full_priceform =QuoteFullPriceForm()
>     item_priceform = QuoteItemPriceForm()
>
> elif request.method == 'POST':
>     full_priceform =QuoteFullPriceForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
>     item_priceform = QuoteItemPriceForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
>
>     if full_priceform.is_valid() and item_priceform.is_valid():
>         full_priceform = full_priceform.save(commit=False)
>         full_priceform.receiver = requestedquotation.sender
>         full_priceform.sender = request.user
>         full_priceform.requestedquotation = requestedquotation
>         full_priceform.save()
>
>         for form in item_priceform:
>             form = item_priceform.save(commit=False)
>             form.full_price = full_priceform
>             form.the_rfq = requestedquotation
>             form.item = items
>             form.save()
>
>         messages.success(request, 'Uploaded'\
>                                   'successfully')
>
>         return redirect('/')
>
>     else:
>         messages.error(request, 'Error While Uploading')     
>
> context = {
>     'full_priceform':full_priceform,
>     'item_priceform':item_priceform,
>     'requestedquotation':requestedquotation,
>     'items':items,
>
> }
>
> return render(request, template_name, context)
> ```

```html
                            <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="{% url 'rfq:quote' requestedquotation.pk %}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                    {% csrf_token %}

                                {% for item in items %}
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="center"><span class="badge badge-primary">#{{ item.pk }}</span></td>
                                    <td align="center">{{ item.name }}</td>
                                    <td align="center">{{ item.discription|safe|linebreaksbr }}</td>
                                    <td align="center"><img src="{% if item.image %} {{ item.image.url }} {% else %} {% static 'img/default.jpg' %} {% endif %}" alt="..." height="150" width="150"></td>
                                    <td align="center">{{ item.quantity }}</td>
                                    <td align="center">{{ item_priceform }}</td>
                                </tr>
                                {% endfor %}
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    {{ full_priceform.subtotal }} 
                    {{ full_priceform.delivery_charges }} 
                    {{ full_priceform.overall_total }} 
                    {{ full_priceform.validity_start_date }} 
                    {{ full_priceform.validity_end_date }} 
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success mb-2">Submit</button>
                    </form>
```

Comment: Can you share the full traceback? There is no `RfqReply` model shared in your question

Comment: Sorry ended up changing the model structure. To what is displayed in the code. Did not realise that the traceback still referenced the previous model. I have updated the title (Traceback Error)

Comment: `items` is a queryset of potentially multiple `RequestForQuotationItem` objects. You cannot assign this to a foreign key - `form.item = items`

Comment: Meaning i have to change the item field from a foreignkey to a ManyToManyField?